# Python 2.7: Persisting search and indexing

Tags: python, search, dictionary, indexing

I wrote a small 'search enginge' that finds all the text files in a Directory and its sub-directories - I can edit the code in but I don't think it is necessary for my question.

It works by creating a dictionary in a format like this:

```
term_frequency = {'file1' : { 'WORD1' : 1, 'WORD2' : 2, 'WORD3' : 3}}
                 {'file2' : { 'WORD1' : 1, 'WORD3' : 3, 'WORD4' : 4}}
                 ...continues with all the files it has found...
```

From gathered information it creates a second dictionary like such:

```
document_frequency = {'WORD1' : ['file1', 'file2'....],
                      'WORD2' : ['file1',............],
                        ....every found word..........]}
```

The purpose of the `term_frequency dictionary` is to hold data of how many times a word has been used in that file and `document_frequency` says in how many documents the word has been used.

Then, when given a word it calculates the relevance of every file by `tf/df` and lists the `non-zero` values in descending relevance of files.

for example:

```
file1 : 0.75
file2 : 0.5
```

I am aware that this is a very simple representation of the tf-idf but I am new to python and programming (2 weeks) and am getting familiar with it all.

Sorry for the long-ish intro but I feel it is relevant to the question... which brings me right to it:

How do I go about making an indexer that saves those dictionaries in a file and then make a 'searcher' read those dictionaries from a file. Because the issue right now is that every time you want to look for a different word it has to read ALL the files once again and make the same 2 dictionaries over and over.

Comment: I think you're looking to [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) your dictionaries.

Comment: @will ahh, I have no idea why but I cannot access any page on 'docs.python', my internet is running very well and it just hates that wesbite... so frustrating :/

Comment: Oops. Okay, looks like I was beaten to it. Sorry.

Comment: @Phillammon dw, thanks a lot for trying to help, I'll try on a different computer or something

Comment: I've added an actual answer to my answer, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The pickle (and for that matter cPickle)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) library is your friend here. By using pickle.dump(), you can turn the entire dictionary into one file which can be read back later by pickle.load().

In this case, you could use something like this:

```
import pickle
termfile = open('terms.pkl', 'wb')
documentfile = open('documents.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(term_frequency, termfile)
pickle.dump(document_frequency, documentfile)
termfile.close()
documentfile.close()
```

and read it back like so:

```
termfile = open('terms.pkl', 'rb')
documentfile = open('documents.pkl', 'rb')
term_frequency = pickle.load(termfile)
document_frequency = pickle.load(documentfile)
termfile.close()
documentfile.close()
```

Comment: I have implemented that code, the first part works perfectly, however when I try to load the dictionaries in another script, it returns an EOF Error and I'm not sure why